# Is it possible for a layman to achieve enlightenment?

Tags: lay-buddhism

Is it possible for a layman to achieve enlightenment by his or her own study without joining the temple and robes? As some of you may know I have studied as a recluse for many yrs and am again considering the possibility of becoming a monk in a temple.

The question is do I need approval from the temple etc to become enlightened or is it possible with doctrines to achieve liberation from suffering on my own experience?

Comment: What I know (realised update) there is no permanent self . the I am is only elements . to extinguish my craving is too ID my own desire ie.to b famous / have a nice wife etc the physical/ material world has very little happiness in it ..I can create my own happiness!

Comment: From what you wrote here it seems you do not really get the teaching. Enlightenment is not an escape from life, or negation to life, "self"/ "I am" you wrote is not correct understanding in the Buddhist teaching. Therefore if you base on this to make your question, it will not come out with a correct answer.